# android image button

Tags: java, android, events, imagebutton

I would like to ask the use of image button in Android programming when simple button can also add the image with the button. How can we generate click event of image button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageButton inherits from ImageView and has its own properties compared to Button properties.

you can check properties here,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Make your activity implement OnClickListener, then 
in OnCreate() or after that event.
use ,

```
ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this); or 
//ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtnid)
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

in onClick() function you can handle the click event

Answer (score 2):

Go to your activity's xml layout and add this...attribute to specific ImageButton...

android:onClick="--In here just write method name which you have in your .java--"

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

This as this type you get click event

```
ImageButton imgbtn=new ImageButton(this);
imgbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }           
});
```